# WinSCP - Host key algorithm preference

Tags: ssh, sftp, winscp

If I move RSA to the top of the list, why don't I see the ssh-rsa 2048 key instead of the ssh-ed25519 256 key.

[image]

It shows: WinSCP shows: ssh-ed25519 256 ff:2e:5e:33:7a:15:de:69:18:cf:82:ae:f0:4e:7b:d2 (when I click "Session", then "Server/Protocol Information").  Is this thumbprint not related to the above key exchange algorithm options?

This is a follow-up to this thread that I started: [Convert Ed25519 to RSA fingerprint (or how to find SSH fingerprint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985106/convert-ed25519-to-rsa-fingerprint-or-how-to-find-ssh-fingerprint/43985404#43985404)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key exchange algorithm and host key algorithm are different things.

WinSCP does not have a configuration option to select host key algorithm.

---

Though, there a hidden [raw session settings `HostKey`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawsettings#hostkey) to configure the host key type priority.

Since WinSCP 5.16, you can [configure it in the GUI](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_raw). For details, see the answer by @Joeri.

---

Alternatively, you can [configure site with preferred host key algorithm in PuTTY](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-hostkey) and [import the site to WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_import).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can change the order of the host key algorithm list for a specific site in WinSCP.
I use WinSCP version 5.17.10 (Build 11087).

How to get it done?

1. Assuming you have created a site...

   [image: Site overview]
2. Click *Edit*
3. Click the arrow next to *Advanced*
4. Click *Edit raw settings*

   [image: Edit Raw Settings]
5. Add your custom host key preference list on a new line:

   ```
   HostKey=rsa,ed25519,ecdsa,dsa,WARN`
   ```

   [image: Add host key preference list]
6. Save all changes

---

The host key algorithm of the fingerprint will depend on the server's keys AND your custom preference list.
In my case, it's RSA:

[image: Fingerprint information]

---

WinSCP documentation on the Raw Settings (look for HostKey):
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawsettings